# rails 3 form_tag method: :get to include only the fields that were changed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, activeview

I'm writing a search form that will reload the page adding to the URL the search parameters.

Currently the URL generated by my form contains all the form fields, including the empty ones. This clutters a lot the url generated with data that is often not needed.

I would like my form to redirect to an url that only has the fields that contain data.

There's the code for my form:

```
= form_tag orders_path, method: :get do
    = text_field_tag :search, params[:search], class: "span2 appendedInputButtons"
    = select_tag "order_types", 
      options_from_collection_for_select(OrderType.all, :id, :name),
      multiple: true, 
      size: 8, 
      include_blank: "select"
    %button.btn.btn-primary Update list
```

When I hit the submit button without filling any of the form I get redirected to an url like this:

```
http://localhost:3000/orders?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=&order_types%5B%5D=
```

while I would like the url to be like this:

```
http://localhost:3000/orders
```

and if I select only some of the `order_types` I get:

```
http://localhost:3000/orders?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=&order_types%5B%5D=3&order_types%5B%5D=6
```

while I would like it to be like:

```
http://localhost:3000/orders?order_types%5B%5D=3&order_types%5B%5D=6
```

or even better:

```
http://localhost:3000/orders?order_types=3,6
```

or something similar, but more concise,

Thanks a lot for any help,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`form_for` binds the form to an object and rails internals will namespace the fields related to this object (or objects) with a prefix, so that when the form is submitted the data will appear in params as `params[:prefix][:some_data]`.

To reduce the size of the query string I would suggest you to use `form_tag` and [build the form manually](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/form_tag). In this way you can have full control over the submitted fields and also avoid the `utf8=%E2%9C%93` utf8 enforcement snowmen hack.

Comment: Thanks, `form_tag` is actually the helper I used, and the form must contain all the fields for the attributes I want to select for.

What I'm not sure about is how to reduce the size of the url generated.

Comment: Try using `= form_tag orders_path, method: :get, enforce_utf8: false do` which will remove the utf8 enforcement. To remove the `search=` from the url you will have to use javascript to exclude/disable (using `disabled='disabled'` attribute of the html element) the field from the form before submit, otherwise it will be always sent in the query string.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, `enforce_utf8: false` isn't working for me, the `disabled` idea I'm not sure I get it, are you suggesting to have ajax add the attribute dynamically after the submit button is pressed?

Comment: `enforce_utf8: false` has been introduced in Rails 4 -> [form tag helper](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/e20dd73df42d63b206d221e2258cc6dc7b1e6068/actionview/lib/action_view/helpers/form_tag_helper.rb#L41).
About the "disabled" attribute - yes, you will have to have javascript doing this.